# AWS Where to put the https certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I would like to make the following structure for my web application

Visitor ==>>> CloudFront-> ALB -> ASG (nginx servers)

I have only one HTTPS certificate for my domain name. I will upload it to ACM but where to attach?
To the Cloudfront? Or to the ALB? Maybe to the hosts? Or everywhere the same?

Can I use the same in all places?

I tried to add it only to the NGINX but it can be used only locally and others from acm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can use SSL on all levels (cloudfront, ALB, and Nginx Servers).

- For Cloudfront, you need to upload your cert to ACM on us-east-1 region.

  > On clodfrount configuration page select alternate domain and put your domain to be used, then it will ask cert you need to select it from selection options.
- For ALB you need upload it to ACM on ALB region.

  > While you go to listeners, then you configure listener for 443 or another you can select SSL cert on there.
- For Nginx, you can use configure your nginx.conf to use cert. It will ask cert and key, you will put them on somewhere at disk.

BTW, You can configure only on cloudfront for visitors and you don't need to use SSL for internal communication if your data is not too important (Credit card etc.)

Comment: Thank you. It means if I setup the ALB to receive traffic only from the Cloudfront, its enough to setup the SSL on the cloudfront and attach the domain to the cloudfront distribution in the Route 53?

Comment: yes, it is correct